# Get page source using Java is reading only 1st line

Tags: java, php, google-app-engine

I have never used java in my life,But i am very good in php , I want to get page source of an website.But i am using Appspot(GAE) .Where file_get_contents and Curl is not working.So i want to get page source via java.I learnt some basics of java and found below code , But below code is getting only 1st line of external page.Please guide me where i am wrong.

```
<?php

function get($url){

        import java.net.URL;
        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;

        $java_url = new URL($url);
        $java_bufferreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader($java_url->openStream()));

        while (($line = $java_bufferreader->readLine()) != null) {
            $content .= $line;
        }

        return $content;
}


echo get("http://domain.com");

?>
```

For example , if i scrape stackoverflow.com its returning only below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>        <title>Stack Overflow</title>    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">    <link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png">    <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml">    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">    <meta name="twitter:domain" content="stackoverflow.com"/>    <meta name="og:type" content="website" />    <meta name="og:image" content="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=fde65a5a78c6"/>    <meta name="og:title" content="Stack Overflow" />    <meta name="og:description" content="Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers" />    <meta name="og:url" content="http://stackoverflow.com/"/>
```

Comment: what do you mean file_get_contents is not working? it works fine for reading http streams in GAE PHP.

Comment: i am not using official GAE php

Answer (score 0):

Try with the **Scanner** class.

```
<?php

function get($url){

        import java.net.URL;
        import java.util.Scanner;

        $java_url = new URL($url);
        $java_scanner = new Scanner($java_url->openStream());

        while (($line = $java_scanner->nextLine()) != null) {
            $content .= $line;
        }

        return $content;
}


echo get("http://domain.com");

?>
```

If that does not work either, initialize variable **content** with an empty string, just in case. :)

Comment: Can you put `$content = '';` after import lines and try it like that?

Comment: I think its stopping when the line is null ,